# ignore string in jquery replace regex with word boundries

Tags: jquery, regex

I use a regex with `replace` in jquery that finds all the words in a definition and replaces them with a custom link that links to a page of that word. Problem I have is that in some of my definitions have a `<a>` link in the definition.

**Example Correct Input**

```
This is a definition of a word in my database <a href="http://www.example.com">[source]</a>.
```

**Example Correct Output**

```
This is a <a href="/dictionary/word/definition">definition</a> of a <a href="/dictionary/word/word">word</a> in my <a href="/dictionary/word/database">database</a> <a href="http://www.example.com">[source]</a>.
```

I use an array of stop words so it does not apply the custom link to those kinds of words like

```
var stopwords = ["a", "about", "above", "across", "after",...
```

Problem is when I inspect the HTML of the page it changes the `href` of that link in the definition like this.

```
This is a <a href="/dictionary/word/definition">definition</a> of a <a href="/dictionary/word/word">word</a> in my <a href="/dictionary/word/database">database</a> <a href="/dictionary/word/source">[source]</a>.
```

It is changing the `http://www.example.com` to `/dictionary/word/souce` which I dont want it to do. Is there any way I can preserve this [source] link, but work as normal for all the other words?

```
$('.definition').html(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(/\b[\w-]+\b/g, function(m){
        if ($.inArray(m.toLowerCase(), stopwords) === -1) {
            return ' <a href="/dictionary/word/' + m.toLowerCase() + '/">' + m + '</a>';
        } else {
            return " "+m;
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: what is stopwords

Comment: I was asking for the words in your list

Comment: I made the edit

Answer (score 0):

Using a only-regex solution may not be appropriate to handle dom strings, instead you can do something like do the replacement only of text nodes inside the target element

```js
var stopwords = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'of', 'in', 'my', '', '[source]', '', '', '', '', '', ''];

$('.definition').contents().each(function process() {
  //console.log(this, this.nodeType);
  if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    var content = $(this).text().replace(/\b[\w-]+\b/g, function(m) {
      if ($.inArray(m.toLowerCase(), stopwords) === -1) {
        return ' <a href="/dictionary/word/' + m.toLowerCase() + '/">' + m + '</a>';
      } else {
        return " " + m;
      }
    });

    $(this).replaceWith(content);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="definition">
  This is a definition of a word in my database <a href="http://www.example.com">[source]</a>.
</div>
```